# Modificar serializer no django rest framework com to_representation

Tags: python, json, api, django, django-rest-framework

Estou desenvolvendo uma API com django rest framework, nela tenho um models onde cadastro contatos, o campo "contato2" é opcional, aqui o meu models:

```
class Contato(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contato1 = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    contato2 = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
```

Estou tentando alterar a visualização do meu JSON, caso o campo "contato2" estiver vazio, eu gostaria que não mostrasse {"contato2" : null }  na saida do meu json

a minha saída esta assim:

```
{
    "cliente": "Robson",
    "contato1": "(11) 98000-0000",
    "contato2": "(11) 98111-1111"
},
{
    "cliente": "Maria",
    "contato1": "(11) 92222-2222",
    "contato2": null
},
```

e assim é como eu gostaria que ficasse:

```
{
    "cliente": "Robson",
    "contato1": "(11) 98000-0000",
    "contato2": "(11) 98111-1111"
},
{
    "cliente": "Maria",
    "contato1": "(11) 92222-2222",
},
```

Na minha class serializer tentei usar o to_representation porem não tive sucesso e a documentação sobre o uso to_representation é bem curta. Esse método é usado para alterar a representação dos dados no json.

Segue o link da documentação:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Aqui está meu código atual na class Serializer:

```
class ContatoSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta: 
        model = Contato
        fields = ('cliente', 'contato1')

        def to_representation(self, instance):
            representation = super().to_representation(instance)
            if instance.contato2:
                representation['contato2'] = instance.contato2
            return representation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é fazendo uma verificação se o atributo é nulo durante o momento da renderização da lista. E caso o valor do atributo `contato2` ser nulo, então removemos este atributo da listagem.

Talvez um dos motivos de não ter conseguido é que a indentação do método `to_representation` deve estar fora do escopo do `class Meta`.
Deve estar portanto, no escopo da classe.

Segue um exemplo de implementação:

```
class ContatoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contato
        fields = ('cliente','contato1', 'contato2')
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        if representation.get('contato2') is None:
            representation.pop('contato2')
    
        return representation
```

Para fazer esta operação utilizamos o método [pop](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop). Se verificar a documentação verá que este método possui um parâmetro obrigatório chamado `key`.

> Se key está no dicionário, remove a mesma e retorna o seu valor, caso
> contrário retorna default. Se default não foi fornecido e key não está
> no dicionário, um `KeyError` é lançado.

Isso vai remover o atributo passado como parâmetro do dicionário. Neste caso será o atributo `contato2`.

Repare que ele exibirá sem o atributo contato2 apenas no caso em que o valor daquela coluna é `nulo` (null, que em Python seria `None`), se é a string vazia (`''`) ele irá exibir, neste caso é só adaptar a solução para o seu caso de uso.

Comment: Funciona, obrigado.